# How can i fix the following error in react native ERROR [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF]

Tags: react-native, api, form-data

I keep getting

> ERROR  [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF]

in my react native project each time i tried to submit the following form data to an API:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Image, Alert, ScrollView, Platform, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const [userSess, setUserSess] = useState('');
const [staffUserSess, setStaffUserSess] = useState('');
const validateURL = new RegExp('(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?');
const pf = /^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;
const [adHeadline, setAdHeadline] = useState('');
const [adCategory, setAdCategory] = useState(null);
const [subCategory, setSubCategory] = useState(null);
const [adDescription, setAdDescription] = useState('');
const [adPrice, setAdPrice] = useState(0);
const [oldAdPrice, setOldAdPrice] = useState(0);
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
const [itemQuantity, setItemQuantity] = useState(1);
const [state, setItemState] = useState('');
const [city, setItemCity] = useState('');
const [sellerStoreAddress, setSellerStoreAddress] = useState('');
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
const [adService, setAdService] = useState('');
const [adURL, setAdURL] = useState('');
const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);


const data_f = new FormData();
if (disSession !== null) {
                data_f.append('beraty_auth', userSessD);
             } else if (disSession2 !== null) {
                data_f.append('store_staff_auth', userSessD);
             }
            data_f.append("ad_headline", adHeadline);
            data_f.append("ad_description", adDescription);
            data_f.append("ad_price", adPrice);
            data_f.append("old_ad_price", oldAdPrice);
            data_f.append("item_quantity", itemQuantity);
            data_f.append("state", state);
            data_f.append("city", city);
            data_f.append("seller_store_address", sellerStoreAddress);
            data_f.append("phone_number", phoneNumber);
            data_f.append("ad_service", adService);
            data_f.append("ad_category", adCategory);
            data_f.append("sub_category", subCategory);
            data_f.append("ad_url", adURL);
            data_f.append("create_ad_btn", "clicked");
            
            if(photo?.length > 0) {
                photo.map((image, index) => {
                  data_f.append("ad_picture[]", {
                    uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? image.uri : image.uri.replace('file://', ''),
                    type: image.type,
                    name: image.fileName,
                  });
                });
            }
             await fetch('https://store.beraty.com/api/create-ad-for-storefront-api.php', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              // body: data_f,
              body: JSON.stringify(data_f),
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data_f))
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson.message === 'sent') {
                //Hide Loader
                setLoading(false);
                Alert.alert(
                  'Success',
                  'Ad created successfully'
                );
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            //Hide Loader
            setLoading(false);
            console.error(error);
            Alert.alert(
                  'Error',
                  'Oops! Sorry! Our engineers are working on the issue. Or kindly check your internet connection and try again.'
            );
          });
```

What could be wrong exactly? I can't seem to post an item to my API through my react native project but when i tested it from API testing tools like postman, thunder client, reqbin.com, etc, it's posting, which shows that there's nothing wrong with my API, but it's not working when posting directly from the app.